# Blank Swift Application Crashes 1-3 times after restart in Distribution and starts working fine

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, crash, dylib

Application goes as follows.
 1. Swift blank application, used deployment target 7.1. No internet connection(mostly closed network). Enterprise distribution
 2. Works fine in simulator and device when watchdog timer is not there.
 3. In distribution, application works fine.
 4. If device restarted and then open the app, it waits for sometime and crashes. If taken again in like 1-3 times, it works.
 5. Once started, the application works fine without any issue.

The application hasn't even started and is crashing while loading libraries. I am providing the crashreport.

```
`Incident Identifier: A928CA67-3484-4D59-86F5-AB1B496C69CF
CrashReporter Key:   51b4398b2962b695f7e2317cd99aa93135f0ed04
Hardware Model:      iPad5,3
Process:             testapp [163]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/3865D55D-0057-4EB3-8155-79239F20FB16/testapp.app/testapp
Identifier:          com.epcs.testapp
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-07-08 10:02:52.892 +0900
Launch Time:         2015-07-08 10:02:24.751 +0900
OS Version:          iOS 8.1 (12B410)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
com.epcs.testapp failed to launch in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 3.590 (user 3.590, system 0.000), 6% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.004, 0% CPU

Thread 0:
0   dyld                            0x00000001200919c8 0x120070000 + 137672
1   dyld                            0x00000001200913d4 0x120070000 + 136148
2   dyld                            0x000000012007f908 0x120070000 + 63752
3   dyld                            0x00000001200822fc 0x120070000 + 74492
4   dyld                            0x000000012007e8f8 0x120070000 + 59640
5   dyld                            0x0000000120073900 0x120070000 + 14592
6   dyld                            0x00000001200780c8 0x120070000 + 32968
7   dyld                            0x0000000120077f88 0x120070000 + 32648
8   dyld                            0x0000000120077cd0 0x120070000 + 31952
9   dyld                            0x0000000120077940 0x120070000 + 31040
10  dyld                            0x0000000120077468 0x120070000 + 29800
11  dyld                            0x0000000120073444 0x120070000 + 13380
12  dyld                            0x00000001200730f8 0x120070000 + 12536
13  dyld                            0x0000000120076ea4 0x120070000 + 28324
14  dyld                            0x000000012007c66c 0x120070000 + 50796
15  dyld                            0x000000012007c354 0x120070000 + 50004
16  dyld                            0x00000001200748e0 0x120070000 + 18656
17  dyld                            0x0000000120075718 0x120070000 + 22296
18  dyld                            0x0000000120071040 0x120070000 + 4160

No thread state (register information) available
Binary Images:
0x100020000 - 0x10002bfff testapp arm64  <720ce02f226e3e2fa2e1c117c00ad794> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/3865D55D-0057-4EB3-8155-79239F20FB16/testapp.app/testapp
0x100038000 - 0x1001c3fff libswiftCore.dylib arm64  <be7f445c675e3a9c89f816c6561566d4> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/3865D55D-0057-4EB3-8155-79239F20FB16/testapp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
0x10031c000 - 0x100333fff libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib arm64  <160e383ca0b23c69876ae5f079114a4b> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/3865D55D-0057-4EB3-8155-79239F20FB16/testapp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
0x120070000 - 0x120097fff dyld arm64  <f958ba064181388a9658f927da42e9e7> /usr/lib/dyld
0x182114000 - 0x18246ffff CoreFoundation arm64  <dd02b6d84f42391cab1b1812b68032cd> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x183014000 - 0x183268fff Foundation arm64  <468d76111ff238edaa1c603530a715ce> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x1869d8000 - 0x18734bfff UIKit arm64  <a76ac80f62d63761a00df6d7963d6116> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x192210000 - 0x192211fff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <85311cdfce9a37178346f06cfea6dc94> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x192d20000 - 0x192f1cfff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <e6224d745a023588af8e5bb67498139a> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
```

Comment: See here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798248/debugging-failed-to-launch-in-time-with-xcode and if possible post your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

Comment: The app works fine in iOS8. Also its not even reaching didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. But I can post the contents if it can be of some help.

Comment: Comments on that other question and similar threads thrown up by a search seem to indicate that this exception is caused by that method not completing in time, but I don't know for sure.  The other place to look is in your main.  It seems that some library may be incompatible with iOS7 but without more clues it is hard to suggest anything more.

Comment: The only library added other than the system frameworks is Crittercism. Does sqlite.dylib matter? Should I include any of these as embedded binary?

Comment: Do you do any large database initialisation/set up on first run?  The fact that once it has run it continues to run until you reset points to some sort of first-time initialisation

Comment: No, I am not doing anything of that sort. I have added the code. Please check and tell me if any issues are there.

Comment: Have you tried commenting the first two lines - the crash reporter and exception handler?

Comment: Sorry to reply so late. But when I removed everything from didFinish the app started working on all devices. Now only the issue is if i restart the device and take the app, it crashes. When taken again like 1-3 times, it starts working. Can it still be an issue related to coding?!!

Comment: Well, this behaviour only happens with your app, so it must be something in code somewhere...

Comment: I tried with a blank app. I updated the Qn. The same thing happened with all the devices irrespective of the iOS version. Also the crash report is there.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is something broken in your build environment.  If you can upload the project somewhere I can try and compile it

Comment: Ya sure. App works fine in normal start, after hard reset and then start. even when erased everything, installed and then start. Only a normal device restart and then start crashes the app. Enterprise distribution and closed network are conditions. 
     
Sorry again to be late. This is the wetrasnfer link. 
we.tl/GBuQxWenV4 
Please check whether there is any issue in build settings and all. The conditions in which I test are given above. Please go through the app.

Comment: I can't test with Enterprise distribution, but I did test an instrument build (which should have 'release' optimisation/build settings).  I ran the app - no problems.  Power cycled my iPad & ran the app - no problems. Turned on Airplane mode - power cycled & ran the app - no problems.  This is on an iPad air 2 with iOS 8.4

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort Paul. Still confused why its crashing on the iPads after normal restart. Works fine after 1-3 crashes.